# SQL Query- Not able to compare fields values?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have `played_dt` column in `widget_event_data` table.
`plyed_dt` hold date in this format ***2009-06-16 21:38:07***

I want to get rows whose `played_dt` contains ***2009-06-16***

Is there any way to do this. How can i write sql query for this??

would be grateful for help..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
WHERE DATE(played_dt) = '2009-06-16'
```

Answer (score 2):

```
select * from your_table
where played_dt like '2009-06-16%'
```

Comment: what is use of %??   
Can you please tell me??

Comment: % is the string wild card matcher

Comment: `%`is a wildcard meaning the datestring has to match only the date and not the rest.

Answer (score 0):

```
select * from table where played_dt = '2009-06-16'
```

will works in oracle.

Answer (score 0):

Use `DATE()` function. Try this:

```
select * 
FROM widget_event_data
where DATE(played_dt) = DATE('2009-06-16')
```

Answer (score 0):

`select * from tableName

 where played_dt = str_to_date('2009-06-16', '%Y-%m-%d')`

see more [mysql str_to_date](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_str-to-date)